# Potential mistake on theorem regarding separability on Topology by James Dugundji

Tags: general-topology, fake-proofs, separable-spaces

I think there must be a mistake on the following statement (from the book Topology by James Dugundji. Chap, VIII sec, 7)

> **7.2 Theorem** (1). The continuous image of a separable space is separable.
> (2). [...]
> *Proof:* (1). Let $f\colon X\to Y$ be continuous and $D\subseteq X$ be dense; since $Y=f(X)=f(\overline{D})\subseteq \overline{f(D)}$, $f(D)$ is dense in $Y$.
> (2). [...]

My problem is with the statement $Y=f(X)$. At no point did we assume $f$ to be a surjection. Am I missing something? How can we state $Y=f(X)$?

**Definition.** A Hausdorff space is *separable* if it contains a countable dense set.

Comment: isn’t image meaning that $Y=f(X)$?

Comment: @onvri, so whenever I mention a function $f\colon X\to Y$ and make a statement of it's image, $f$ being a surjection is then implied?

Comment: I think if you write $f: X \to Y$, you have to write $Z=f(X)$ and I believe the theorem should apply on $Z$(equivalently apply the theorem on the function $\widetilde{f}: X\to Z$ that limits the codomain of $f $)

Comment: @onriv I agree, I think the author is abusing notation here.

Comment: Yeah, sloppy but not wrong.

Comment: I've noticed that, for simple proofs, he tries to make them as short as possible. This might be what leads to this sort of things.

Comment: He could write: without loss of generality we can assume that $f(X)=Y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know whether Dugundji gives a formal definition of "continuous image" somewhere in his book. But Theorem V 1.4 contains a text passage coming close to such a definition:

> The continuous image of a connected set is connected. That is, if $X$ is connected and $f : X \to Y$ is continuous, then $f(X)$ is connected.

Formally we should define a space $Y$ to be *the continuous image of a space $X$* if there exists a continuous surjection $f : X \to Y$.

Thus you are right, he should have written

> *Proof:* (1). Let $f\colon X\to Y$ be a continuous surjection and ...

But I think Dugundjis's omission of "surjection" is a forgivable sin.